Ethics application: secondary analysis of anonymous data without "future use" consent
I am submitting an ethics approval application for secondary analysis of 3 existing (anonymized but not public) datasets. The consent forms for these 3 studies made no mention of "future data use" like the secondary analyses I'm proposing.
Could this be a reason for my ethics application to be rejected (permanently)? I imagine this situation could arise often. The risks to participants seem minor due to anonymity.

Is it fully or pseudo-anonymised?

You can't do anything without IRB approval anyway, so there is no risk to just asking your IRB folks this question: Either they say that you will likely be approved (in which case you'll write your IRB application) or they say that you will likely not be approved (in which case you haven't lost any time either). In neither case is there any risk in having an informal conversation with your IRB staff.
The only case where there is a risk is if you were planning on doing the analysis anyway but did not want to tip off IRB if you thought they might not approve your application. But I can only assume that that wasn't what you had in mind because that's one way to risk getting fired.

The answer is always "Ask your IRB."
